# Merge two Json Object PHP (not same estructure)

Tags: php, json, laravel, array-merge

Hello i have a two json object's

Json 1

```
{
  "id": null,
  "type": "NE",
  "info": {
    "name": "Ne",
    "last_name: "NE",
    "status": "NE",
    "rfc": "NE",
    "email": "jNE"
   }
  }
```

json 2

```
  {
  "id": 2,
  "type": "PF",
  "info": {
    "status": 1,
    "rfc": "DOSLWOOEOE22",
    "email": "email@email.com"
   }
  }
```

I need merge the json object's, when json 2 override the values in json 1, but the json result contain the keys/values that the json does not have

i need the json result same this:

```
 {
  "id": 2,
  "type": "PF",
  "info": {
    "name": "Ne",
    "last_name: "NE",
    "status": 1,
    "rfc": "DOSLWOOEOE22",
    "email": "email@email.com"
   }
  }
```

**note: i try using array_merge but doesn't work, only override json 2 into json 1 without another keys **

Comment: Does [`array_merge_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) work better?

Comment: works with array_replace_recursive, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Work with array_replace_recursive

```
array_replace_recursive(json_1, json_2)
```